# Discord.js V13 Set Button Cooldown

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I have recently made my ticket bot, but I need to add a cooldown to the "close ticket" button to prevent someone from flooding the button and sending multiple messages, I haven't found any possible way to do that. How would I add a cooldown on a specific button?

My button code:

```
      const row = new client.discord.MessageActionRow()
        .addComponents(
          new client.discord.MessageButton()
          .setCustomId('confirm-close')
          .setLabel('Fechar o Ticket')
          .setStyle('DANGER'),
          new client.discord.MessageButton()
          .setCustomId('no')
          .setLabel('Cancelar Fechamento')
          .setStyle('SECONDARY'),
        );

        const verif = await interaction.reply({
          content: 'Tem certeza de que deseja fechar o ticket?',
          components: [row]
        });
```

For user identification, I'm using `interaction.user.id`

Comment: What is the operation that you try to avoid being executed while the cooldown period has not elapsed yet?

Comment: the operation
`new client.discord.MessageButton()
          .setCustomId('confirm-close')
          .setLabel('Fechar o Ticket')
          .setStyle('DANGER'),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you can do something like this for a cooldown:

```js
let cooldownTime = 5000; //five seconds
let semaphore = true; //green

function doSomeStuff() {
    if (semaphore) {
        //your logic
        console.log("GREEN");
        semaphore = false; //red
        setTimeout(() => {semaphore = true;}, cooldownTime);
    } else {
        console.log("RED");
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="CLICK ME!" onclick="doSomeStuff()">
```

This only affects the logic, but you can add button disabling/enabling to it as well.